# Sorting slice according to value having a map[string]interface items

Tags: go

After Edit

The real situation is a little different from the sample data.

I have a table having all the fields and properties related to user interface I use in the application. I need a simple slice ordered by listorder having only fields name list like this.

```
colons=[]string{'id', 'name', 'population', 'phonecode'}
```

But the data source is a slice consist of `map[string]interface{}` values getting from a sql query like this

```
select fieldname, 
       label, 
       listorder 
  from tablefields 
 where tablename="city"  
 order by fieldname


fields := []map[string]interface{} {
  {"fieldname": "id",         "label": "Id No",      "listorder": "01"},
  {"fieldname": "name",  ,    "label": "City Name",  "listorder": "03"},
  {"fieldname": "phonecode",  "label": "Phone Code", "listorder": "02"},
  {"fieldname": "population", "label": "Population", "listorder": "04"},
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what problems are you having? Please include your attempt in the question. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Please post the attempt you have tried to resolve your problem.

Comment: Just adapt [the sort package example](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example_) to work with maps instead of structs. This question is essentially "How do I access the 'population' field in my map?"

Comment: Thanks Peter, Your recommendation made me solve it. The solution: https://play.golang.org/p/7AVfIt_Zihx

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem after getting tip from Peter in the comment.

The solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type ByListOrder []map[string]interface{}

func (a ByListOrder) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a ByListOrder) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByListOrder) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i]["listorder"].(string) < a[j]["listorder"].(string) }


func main() {
    fields := []map[string]interface{} {
          {"fieldname": "id",         "label": "Id No",      "listorder": "01"},
          {"fieldname": "name",       "label": "City Name",  "listorder": "03"},
          {"fieldname": "phonecode",  "label": "Phone Code", "listorder": "02"},
          {"fieldname": "population", "label": "Population", "listorder": "04"},
    }      

    fmt.Println(fields)
    sort.Sort(ByListOrder(fields))
    fmt.Println(fields)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7AVfIt_Zihx

Comment: Link-only answers are not particularly helpful for future readers. I took the liberty of pasting it into the answer.